# How to add disk as folder in Ubuntu 14,04?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server

How to add those last disks as folder on system

```
sdc       8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk
sdd       8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk

root@Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal ~ # lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3    8:3    0 191.1G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0   191G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3    8:19   0 191.1G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0   191G  0 raid1 /
sdc       8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk
sdd       8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk
```

Comment: Unfortunately Ubuntu 14.04 is off-topic here, because it is has reached End Of Life (EOL) status, thus not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to create a partition table and create a partition them first

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
```

After that you should see a

```
/dev/sdc1
```

and mount it

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```